# How to set up a SharePoint 2010 developer machine?

Tags: 2010, development, configuration

As the release date for the public beta of SharePoint 2010 is coming closer and closer, I'm wondering how to set up a developer machine for it. I've heard that for developing on SharePoint a 64 bit system is needed and that Microsoft advises to use Windows 7 64 bit and install SharePoint 2010 on it.

I think that won't be an option for me as I only have one computer here at work and I don't like to install SharePoint on the same machine that I use for my normal office work (email stuff, writing concept papers, ...).

Am I right that I only have two other options? Using Server 2008 as a desktop operating system and install SharePoint 2010 on a virtual machine or using Windows 7 64 and use VMWare to host the SharePoitn 2010.

So I'm wondering if there are any other options and which one you chose? What experiences have you already made?

Answer (score 1):

Eli Robillard [wrote a useful post](http://weblogs.asp.net/erobillard/archive/2009/10/29/how-to-build-a-sharepoint-2010-development-machine-part-i.aspx) about this today.

Derek

Answer (score 0):

It's great that we now have options!

I have (since Bamboo made it possible) had WSS 3 installed on my Vista/7 systems - it's great for RAD, and I will continue to have SharePoint Foundation on my main OS (Win 7 x64, 8GB RAM). It's so much quicker if you have to do a demo or build something quickly. For SharePoint Server development I (will) use VMWare Workstation 7 (release a week ago) and develop on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box.

There are as many options as there are developers, and it's great that there now are so many supported ways.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the setup guide from Microsoft. It includes a reference to the SharePoint 2010 Easy Setup Script.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx